# Pass Subscription key from Azure API management Subscription to Azure function ("API")

Tags: azure, access-token, azure-api-management, subscription

Is it possible to pass the subscription key from Azure's API management to the API service?

i.e. if the API is set to use the "unlimited" subscription and its key_ID is 2345-3455-2222
can I read that in an Azure function?

I have tried reading the request `objects.headers` collection and pull back the `ocp-apim-subscription-key` but it returns the subscription of the AZURE function not the API.

Comment: Yes, you can read the Id using `context.Product.Id`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the policies to get the APIM Subscription key.

> I have tried reading the request `objects.headers` collection and pull back the `ocp-apim-subscription-key` but it returns the subscription of the AZURE function not the API.

You can either use `context.Subscription.Key` or `context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "")` to get the APIM subscription key value.

If you want to get the Product Id, you can use    `<set-variable  name="ProductId"  value="@(context.Product.Id)"  />`.

I am able to get the APIM subscription key as shown below-

[image]

In this way, you can pass the subscription key value to function